# Plain Google Maps App - How can I resize the container?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here's my ViewController implementation:

```
    @implementation ViewController

    -
    (void) viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    -
    (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -
    (void) loadView {
            // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
            // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
            GMSCameraPosition * camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: -33.86
                    longitude: 151.20
                    zoom: 6
            ];
            GMSMapView * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectZero camera: camera];
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
            self.view = mapView;

            // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
            GMSMarker * marker = [
                    [GMSMarker alloc] init
            ];
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
            marker.title = @ "Sydney";
            marker.snippet = @ "Australia";
            marker.map = mapView;
    }

    @end
```

How can I resize this window, because right now it spans all over the screen? I want it to be smaller so it fits into a smaller box below the status bar on top.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and add mapView as subview

```
 UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 64, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:yourView];
```

Just replace

```
 GMSMapView * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectZero camera: camera];
```

with

```
 GMSMapView * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: yourView.bounds camera: camera];
```

also replace

```
self.view = mapView;
```

with

```
[yourView addSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: For the last one, [testView addSubview:mapView];, my compiler said use of undeclared identifier "testView".

Comment: My mistake replace it with yourview

Comment: Thanks it has compiled. However, now its just a blank white screen (google maps not load).

Answer (score 0):

**Change this line :**

```
   self.view = mapView;
```

**To :**

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64,300, 300);// Set your Expected size here.
```

> Reason behind your issue is you are setting `mapView` as your main view
>   so its taking mainView size and showing into fullscreen.

Hope this will help you to change your `mapView` size.

Comment: It says Undeclared Identifier "addSubView"

Comment: sorry typo mistake try `[self.view addSubview:mapView];`